# Is it possible to get information from ID3 tag metadata embedded in HLS stream in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, http-live-streaming

I have an HLS stream that streams a live feed with embedded ID3 PRIV Tag to mark a certain points in stream.  Is it possible to get notified or somehow retrieved the data from these tags in Safari, ideally via Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is possible using JavaScript functions, like:

```
video.textTracks.addEventListener('addtrack', function(addTrackEvent) {
  var track  = addTrackEvent.track;
  track.mode = 'hidden';

  track.addEventListener('cuechange', function(cueChangeEvent) {
    // some processing here...
  });
});
```

This is basically based on an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772013/http-live-streaming-how-to-listen-for-timed-metadata-embedded-as-id3-tags-using) about ID3 tags on iOS.

Comment: Tried that, but couldn't get it to work on OSX for some reason. Only works on iOS.