# Timed metadata in MPEG DASH?

Tags: metadata, mpeg-dash

HLS has timed metadata, which can be used from within iOS / OS X (and some Flash-based players) to launch JavaScript events at a certain point in a live video stream by running a JavaScript event handler when the metadata arrives: [HTTP Live Streaming: how to listen for timed metadata embedded as ID3 tags using Javascript in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772013/http-live-streaming-how-to-listen-for-timed-metadata-embedded-as-id3-tags-using)

RTMP (Flash) has cue points, which can be used for the same effect.

Is there any way to do something like this with a live (not VOD) MPEG DASH stream?

Answer (score 3):

With MPEG Dash you can make use of Inline and Inband events. Those events have a presentation time and a unique combination of schemeIdURI and value. In your DASH player you can usually register for that events and will get a callback if they occur.

Inline events are signalled directly in the manifest file, while inband events are multiplexed into specific segments. You can find a working demo and inband events [here](http://se-mashup.fokus.fraunhofer.de:8080/tests/dsi/mws15/dash.js/samples/ad-insertion/adinsertion_inband.html). In that example an event is used to trigger a reload of the manifest file. Nevertheless you also use that mechanism for your own custom events.